# Chef remote_file set maximum number of re-directions to zero

Tags: chef

I am trying to implement the below `wget` download command using chef `remote_file` resource. But I couldn't find a way to avoid the re-directions. The URL that I am trying to access may sometimes be redirected to my ISP bill reminder page. And chef `remote_file` resource downloads this bill reminder HTML page as a zip file.

`wget -N  --max-redirect=0 http://www.someurl.com/file.zip`

The chef recipe resource is

```
remote_file "#{node['download-zip-path']}/#{zip}" do
    source "http://www.someurl.com/#{zip}"
    action :create
    notifies :run, 'execute[unzip_file]', :delayed
end
```

The `--max-redirect=0` flag in `wget` makes sure that there isn't any redirection to ISP page. I can achieve the same using ruby's `open-uri` or `execute` command resource but is there any native chef way to achieve this no/zero re-direction?

Comment: No there's not, failing to download would mean failure of run. The proper course of action is to host the target file on an internal server, don't trust remotes to be available

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The chef-client machines are deployed at customer premises and are connected to the internet through the client's ISPs. The file that is downloaded is vpn config and hence hosing on a internal server is not possible. So I will go ahead with a ruby module and add it as a library for my recipes.

Comment: Yes, you have to bake that yourself

Comment: @Tensibai I have make use of the Down gem in ruby and write a ruby_block resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the remote_file resource couldn't handle redirects. Hence I had to write a ruby_block resource that makes use of 'Down' gem.

```
ruby_block 'download_openvpn_zip' do
    block do 
        attempt = 2
        begin
            retries ||= 0
            tempfile = Down::NetHttp.download("http://www.someurl.com/#{zip},max_redirects: 0)
            FileUtils.mv tempfile.path, "#{node['openvpn-conf-path']}/#{tempfile.original_filename}"
        rescue Down::TooManyRedirects => e
            puts "\n \t ERROR: #{e.message}"
            retry if (retries += 1) < 1
        end 
    end
    action :run
    notifies :run, 'execute[unzip_file]', :delayed
end
```

Comment: Maybe you could have achieved the same thing using the http class of chef, but I'm not really sure. Thanks for sharing your solution anyway :)

Comment: You way have a better experience using `Chef::Log.warn` instead of puts also.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will be using the Chef::Log.warn instead of puts.